# How to know the requested url in guzzle?

Tags: php, guzzle

I try load many urls async but can't think of anything how can I know proccess url..Code below:

```
$requests = function ($total, $urls) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        yield new Request('GET', $urls[$i]);
    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(50, $urls), [
    'concurrency' => 5,
    'fulfilled' => function (Response $response, $index) {
          // How i can this know what url was proccessed? 

    },
    'rejected' => function (RequestException $reason, $index) {
         // And here too..
    },
]);


$promise = $pool->promise();

$promise->wait();
```

Please help, any ideas..

Comment: Oh, idea! I found, that can in **fulfilled** add `use ($urls)` . So will be
`'fulfilled' => function (Response $response, $index) use ($urls){

}`